# Spring Boot Admin client not registering

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

I have a spring boot 1.5.1 service and a spring boot admin 2.0.1.

Those are compatible given this documentation (http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/2.0.0/#monitoring-spring-boot-1.5.x).

Here is my CLIENT setup

My entrypoint

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Run {

    /**
     * Starts the application.
     * @param args the arguments to start the application.
     * @throws Exception if an error occurs.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Run.class, args);
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
    dependencies { 
//other internal dependencies
        compile 'org.modelmapper:modelmapper:0.7.7'
        compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:1.5.1.RELEASE'
        compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.5.1.RELEASE'
        compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:1.5.1.RELEASE'
        compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis:1.5.1.RELEASE'
        compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp:1.5.1.RELEASE'
        compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:1.5.1.RELEASE'
        compile('de.codecentric:spring-boot-admin-starter-client:1.5.7')
        compile 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4-1206-jdbc42'
        provided 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
        provided 'javax.servlet.jsp:javax.servlet.jsp-api:2.3.1'
    }
```

application.yml

```
management:
  security:
    enabled: false
spring:
  boot:
    admin:
      url: http://localhost:8080
```

For the server setup I followed the get started here http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/2.0.0/#_what_is_spring_boot_admin.

Note :

- I think the server setup is ok, because I am able to register the server to itself
- When I start the client, there is nothing talking about SBA client, even if I add "logging.level.de.codecentric.boot.admin: DEBUG" to my application.yml
- There is nothing about the client failing to register on the server's log
- I tried to change the server url with random string to see if I'd get an error but it didn't told anything about that
- There is a configure(httpSecurity) override on the client

What could go wrong ? It seems to me that spring is not starting up the client at all.

Comment: was this problem solved? I am facing exact same issue and could not find any pointer how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

For your Boot 1.5.x application you need to set `spring.boot.admin.api-path=instances`.
See http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/current/#monitoring-spring-boot-1.5.x

Comment: I found this doc, but do you think it could be the problem ? there is nothing talking about the server on the client's log or about this client on the server's

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with a different property?
spring.boot.admin.**client**.url

Answer (score 0):

```
management:
endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

Add this in your application.yml file

Answer (score 0):

I using spring 2.4

with below property files

For admin

server.port = 9090

spring.application.name = adminServer

---

For client

spring.boot.admin.client.url = http://localhost:9090/

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*

spring.boot.admin.client.enabled=true

spring.boot.admin.client.auto-registration=true

spring.boot.admin.client.username=admin

spring.boot.admin.client.password=admin